# AWS - Caching the response of a scheduled lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

Using AWS, I have followed [an example](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-scheduled-weather) of a lambda function using the serverless framework. It is working as expected, but now I wonder what the best way of caching the response is.

My final version of this will consist of one or more json objects that will be retrieved on a regular basis.

The client side will call an api that will retrieve the already cached data.

So what AWS service should I implement to actually make the cache?

Answer (score 0):

If it's static bit of JSON i'd simply import/return it from within the function rather than enable caching, but hey it's your API!

To answer your question you can use caching within API Gateway to do so, documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html)

Update:

I'd actually misread the question so apologies for that, whilst that caching works what the Op is asking is where to store data retrieved - if your retrieving it from an external API you can just write it to s3 like so:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

    export default (event, context, callback) => {
        let s3Bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME' } })
        let documentName = 'someName'
        let fileExtension = 'json'

        let s3data = {
            Key: `${documentName}.${fileExtension}`,
            Body: JSON.parse(event.body.someJsonObject), 
        }

        s3Bucket.putObject(s3data, (err, s3result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                callback(err, null)
            } else {

                console.log('S3 added', s3result)
                callback(null, 'done')
            }
        })
    }
```

Then you just need to read the object back in your serving endpoint.

Comment: But I call it from the scheduled lambda function. I do not see what you mean I should return it to. The client is not at all triggering this external api, and nor should it be. The client side shall only use my already stored/cached data.

Comment: Using api gateway seems like a strange way around the issue. The lambda function is already bing called using a cron schedule, and no other way of triggering this is desired.